# How to set different page size for first page in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

We got the need to display a blog posts page that display X posts - first post is displayed as a header and the rest are in 2 columns. The page has a show more button at the bottom that fetches the next page posts using ajax and adding them at the bottom. 
Is it possible to get X+1 items for the subsequent pages?

Any hint, even in code are welcome since we use a sourced version of orchard installation.

Comment: Which Action do you call from Ajax? Normally, paged actions have a "PagerParameters" - param. The normal pager just adds a queryString like "?pageSize=50", which you could utilize. Shouldn't that be sufficient?

Comment: @Xceno I don't think blog posts in Orchard take into consideration the pagesize if you pass it as a parameter since each blog has its own property for the page size.

Comment: The actual Item-Action on the BlogController takes the parameter mentioned above. (Sourcecode of Orchard 1.10)

You're correct in that the pageSize gets overridden with the one specified in the blogs settings, but you could change that easily.

Comment: I could change it, but it changes for each page, I want the first page to bring 7 posts and then I need 8 posts per page

Answer (score 1):

So before cluttering the comments above this is my proposed solution.

I think there was a slight misunderstanding about changing the controller action which I'd like to clarify (I hope I understood everything correctly now):

**Orchard.Blogs | BlogController | Item Action**

```cs
public ActionResult Item(int blogId, PagerParameters pagerParameters) {
    // This is all original code
    Pager pager = new Pager(_siteService.GetSiteSettings(), pagerParameters);

    var blogPart = _blogService.Get(blogId, VersionOptions.Published).As<BlogPart>();
    if (blogPart == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    if (!_services.Authorizer.Authorize(Orchard.Core.Contents.Permissions.ViewContent, blogPart, T("Cannot view content"))) {
        return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }

    // This is the actual change:
    // Use the pagerParameters provided, otherwise fall back to the blog settings
    pager.PageSize = pagerParameters.PageSize.HasValue ? pager.PageSize : blogPart.PostsPerPage;

    // This is all original code again
    _feedManager.Register(blogPart, _services.ContentManager.GetItemMetadata(blogPart).DisplayText);
    var blogPosts = _blogPostService.Get(blogPart, pager.GetStartIndex(), pager.PageSize) // Your new page size will be used
        .Select(b => _services.ContentManager.BuildDisplay(b, "Summary"));
    dynamic blog = _services.ContentManager.BuildDisplay(blogPart);

    var list = Shape.List();
    list.AddRange(blogPosts);
    blog.Content.Add(Shape.Parts_Blogs_BlogPost_List(ContentItems: list), "5");

    var totalItemCount = _blogPostService.PostCount(blogPart);
    blog.Content.Add(Shape.Pager(pager).TotalItemCount(totalItemCount), "Content:after");

    return new ShapeResult(this, blog);
}
```

So the change is very subtle, but this way I would configure the blogs default pageSize to 7 items and for every subsequent Ajax-Request I'd provide a "pageSize"-Parameter with the desired size.